# Loading Modules In Kamailio Server

Tags: kamailio

I am trying to configure kamailio with xcap. Unfortunately after installing kamailio with xcap and presence module some other dependent module (like pua and rls) is needed. How can i load these module without reinstalling kamailio again. One more thing even pua and rls directory is available but pua.so and rls.so files are missing,which is necessary to load them.

Answer (score 0):

RLS is not needed for XCAP. Also, PUA is not a must, but can be needed if you want some presence extensions, however, independent of XCAP.

Rather old by now, but here is a tutorial with Kamailio and XCAP, not needing RLS or PUA:

- http://kb.asipto.com/kamailio:presence:k31-made-simple

On the other hand, regarding installing new modules, you can install only one module at one time, for rls just do:

```
make install-modules modules=modules/rls
```

I assumed you installed from sources, otherwise the kamailio-presence-modules package (.deb or .rpm) should have all those modules related to presence and xcap.